# Show text in bash/dialogue

Tags: bash

how can I display the text "Selected Item x" to like in the picture?

[image]

```
           ITM=$(dialog --stdout --menu "\nSelect Items...\n " 20 120 0 \
                \
                "item_1" "Item 1" \
                "item_2" "Item 2" \
                "item_3" "Item 3")
```

Comment: Can you post your current code?

Comment: Yes, Question supplemented...

Comment: I don't see anything in the man page that indicates you can display text there. Not to say it's impossible, but I'd set my expectations low :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be one step further

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
items=(
    item_1 "Item 1" "Selected Item 1"
    item_2 "Item 2" "Selected Item 2"
    item_3 "Item 3" "Selected Item 3"
)

dialog --item-help --menu '\nSelected Items...\n' 20 120 0 "${items[@]}"
```

It doesn't look like dialog(1) allows you to position the help text though.